# Get the label of selected ng-option using object notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, label, html-select, ng-options

Given an object:

```
obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}
```

I create an `ng-option` using the object datasource notation:

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="key for (key, value) in obj"></select>
```

At this point the user will see a dropdown with the values `foo` and `bar`. When they select an option the value of `selection` is change to `1` or `2` respectively.

But how can I go back and figure out what the currently selected key/label is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine and compare the *key's value* in your statement, you simply need to add the `select` clause to your `ng-options` expression.

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in obj"></select>
```

This will set `selection` to `foo` or `bar` and not `1` or `2` and you can make your determination from there.

From Angular Docs

> `select` as `label` for (key , value) in object
>
> `select`: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the parent `<select>` element. If not specified, select expression will default to value.

**Update**:

In order to see both key and value, you can create a new object as your `select`.  Check out this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k5fHMU)

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="{key:key, value:value} as key for (key, value) in obj"></select>

<span>{{selection.key}}</span>
<span>{{selection.value}}</span>
```

Comment: I think you understood me backwards. I don't want the `selectedItem`, I want they key associated with the `selectedItem`. IE in my example if the user picks `foo`, `selectedItem` will have the value `1`. How can I then figure out that the user has selected `foo`? Note that I can not have logic like `if selectedItem==1 return "foo"` because the values of the object may not be unique.

Comment: OK, that makes a difference ;)  See my updated answer.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to keep the value of `selection` equal to to the value of the object, not the key, but I guess I can work with the key

Comment: Check out my update, this should get you what you want.

Comment: @jcc : I love your approach to set key, value in model: `{key:key, value:value}`